# setting top.location.hash with %20 in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, hash, swfaddress

In firefox, using this javascript:

```
top.location.hash = "#here%20are%20spaces";
```

changes the browser url to:

```
http://mysite.com/#here are spaces
```

I expected firefox to show the encoded spaces as %20 in the browser url.

1. What's going on here?  Why is firefox not setting the url to the string as I passed it?
2. How can I force firefox to update the url with the encoded characters?

*and...*

If I add set the url to

```
top.location.hash = "#here%20are%20spaces%";
```

It works(!?), albeit with an extra unwanted % appended to the end.  I am not sure if this is a bug or a feature.  Ideas or references on how to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%20` are replaced with an empty space (in firefox 3) just for readability purpose. You shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: For the cutting and pasting of permalinks, it is an issue.

Comment: Why is that, maybe you can explain what exactly your problem is...if you copy and paste such an url that has a space, into a different browser, it is automatically interpreted as %20.

Comment: Wanted to ensure copy and paste would work without line breaks, which I now see it does.

Answer (score 2):

It still seems to be an active [Firefox Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox-3.0/+bug/245521) for this issue (albeit reported for Firefox in Ubuntu, but also seen for other OS)....

Answer (score 2):

Firefox displays the unencoded value in the location bar, as it does for all all URLs that contain encoded values. Try to go to [some url with special characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mot%C3%B6rhead), then cut & paste it to notepad/...

Have you tried if it works anyway and does what you want?

Answer (score 0):

That's a security precaution. If it wasn't there, one could encode character that looks just like "a" in paypal.com string inside your address bar.